# How to get numbers from filenames?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have many files in directory according to the key:

```
pic001.jpg
pic002.jpg
pic012.jpg
[...]
ico001.jpg
ico002.jpg
ico012.jpg
[...]
```

and I want to list this files and create structure like this:

```
for r,d,f in os.walk(directory):
    for file in f:
        if file.startswith("pic"):
            pic = file
            ico = ???
            images_list.append({
                'big': directory + '/' + pic,
                'thumb': directory + '/' + ico,
            })
```

How to get "pic" file and "ico" assigned to him (only if ico exist)?

Comment: `ico = "ico" + file[3:]` (but please don't use the variable name `file`, it shadows a built-in).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the simplest answer seems to be:

```
ico = 'ico' + file[3:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a regular expression.

```
import re
icon = 'ico%s.jpg' % re.findall(r'^pic(\d+).jpg$', file)[0]
```

It's definitely going to be more intuitive and easier to maintain than using slices.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use regexp?

```
import re
...   
m = re.search('\d+', f.name)
print 'ico' + str(m.group(0)) + 'jpg'
```